# Как через JS, создать odt-файл? (doc/docx)

Tags: javascript, файлы, doc

Задача: открыть документ-шаблон, заменить в нём константы на нужный текст и сохранить как новый файл. Есть ли какая-то библиотека на js, позволяющая решить эту задачу? В идеале библиотека для React